# Convergence of solutions from a 1st order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Given the following initial value problem
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x'(t)+p(t)x(t)=g(t) \\ x(0)=1 \end{array}\right.$$
I have to find $p(t)$ and $g(t)$ such that the solutions $x(t)$ converge to $0$ when $t\to+\infty$

Using the integrating factor, I didn't find anything that I think it could help me - just $x(t)$ written as integral of $e^{p(t)}$ etc. On Google, the articles I found are in a high level that I can't understand.

My question is: is there a simple way to make it? Or should I just try to get some functions, like $p(t)=x^2$ and $g(t)=1$ and solve the problem and evaluate the limit?

Comment: Set $x(t) = e^{-t}$ in the equation
$$
- e^{-t} + p(t) e^{-t} = g(t)
$$ you get a relation between $p(t)$ and $g(t)$. Obviously $x(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$

Comment: another example is in the answer, I think you understand now how to get more of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you question correctly, one can determine a relation between $p(t)$ and $g(t)$ by setting $x(t) = e^{-t}$ in the equation you get
$$
- e^{-t} + p(t) e^{-t} = g(t)
$$
Obviously $x(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$ and $x(0) = 1$ as the boundary conditions. Set for example $p(t) = x^2$ you get
$$
g(t) = (p(t) - 1)e^{-t} =  (x^2 - 1)e^{-t}
$$
Try setting $x(t) = e^{-t^2}$ in the equation you get
$$
- 2t e^{-t^2} + p(t) e^{-t^2} = g(t)
$$
you get
$$
g(t) = ( + p(t) - 2t) e^{-t^2}
$$
and as before $x(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$ and $x(0) = 1$